# Is it possible to give a size by ratio to qt designer ?

Tags: qt

For exemple, I want the value of the layoutLeftMargin property to be equal to 1/3 of the parent widget. So when I will resize the windows, the ratio of the widget will still stay the same.

Else, if it's not possible with QtDesigner, how can I do it with code ?

Comment: what kind of layout are you using? vertical, horizontal, grid, or form?

Comment: @Mike I am using a grid layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Margins are specified in pixels, they can't be relative to the parent widget's size.

However, You can do that in the designer by putting your whole current layout in a [Horizontal Layout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhboxlayout.html#details), add a [Horizontal Spacer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspaceritem.html#details) to the left of it, assign suitable [`layoutStretch`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#setStretch) values in the horizontal layout (In your example, this should be `1,2`, meaning the original layout will take up twice the space taken up by the spacer, so that the spacer gets `1/3` of the parent widget).

[image: Designer sample]

[image: Horizontal Layout properties pane]